# tabs (links) are broken after reorder of <li> tab elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery-ui tabs(). Evertihng worked fine.
Then I reordered my tabs in DOM via jquery.

Before:

```
<li id="L1">Tab 1</li>
<li id="L2">Tab 2</li>
```

After:

```
<li id="L2">Tab 2</li>
<li id="L1">Tab 1</li>
```

When i hover my tabs they show correct links to the content-divs.
But by clicking the tabs nothing is happening.

Anyone has an idea whats my fault?

**EDIT:** My code for reordering li-elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var elems = $('#tabsUl').children('li').remove();

  elems.sort(function(a,b){
    return parseInt($(a).attr("data-order")) > parseInt($(b).attr("data-order"));
  });

  $('#tabsUl').append(elems);
});​
```

And the markup example:

```
<ul id="tabsUl">
  <li data-order="4">Item 4</li>
  <li data-order="2">Item 2</li>
  <li data-order="3">Item 3</li>
  <li data-order="1">Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where's the code you're using to re-order the elements?

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/j3K3F/

Comment: @KommiZZar, edit your question with your example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead of `.remove()`.

```
var elems = $('#tabsUl').children('li').detach();
```

Documentation:

> **`.detach()`**
>
> The **`.detach()`** method is the same as **`.remove()`**, except that **`.detach()`** keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much Alexander!

Comment: @KommiZZar, edit your question with the *actual* code, not a link